# How to enable TLS1.3 for wifi connection in ubantu

Tags: wireless, 22.04, authentication, tls, radius

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (jammy), I want to connect access point of wifi network where authentication method is TLS enable. By default connection handsake initiated with EAP_TLS1.2, I want to enable EAP-TLS1.3 or tls1.3 for my system to connect with wifi because my authentication server(AAA or RADIUS server) is supporting tls1.3

Comment: Ubuntu disable RADIUS Tls1.3 because it breaks more systems than it helps with: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1823053 . You can try the opposite of https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#WPA_Enterprise_connections_fail_to_authenticate_with_OpenSSL_%22unsupported_protocol%22_error if a setting even exists